# overflow:auto causing text blanking

Tags: html, css, css-float, overflow

I have a right floating image, followed by a left floating one, with text flowing around both.  I'm trying to use overflow:auto to keep the paragraphs together, but as the viewport is resized then the browser resizes certain paragraphs with crazy dimensions (0x2000). REF: https://jsfiddle.net/5prgjppL/

HTML

```
<div class='content'>
  <div class='pictureOne'>
    <img src='https://dummyimage.com/500' width='100%' alt='Picture One'>
  </div>
  <div class='pictureTwo'>
    <img src='https://dummyimage.com/500' width='100%' alt='Picture Two'>
  </div>
  <div class='text'>
    <p>"Lorem ... est laborum."</p>
    <p>"Lorem ... est laborum."</p>
    ...
    <p>"Lorem ... est laborum."</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.pictureOne {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
.pictureTwo {
  float: left;
  clear: right;
  width: 50%;
}
.text p {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Tested with Chrome and Firefox.  Doesn't happen when overflow is visible or whenone of the pictures is removed.

Is there a fix, or a better way to accomplish the same thing? (The equivalent of the div.text in the fiddle is generated through a ckeditor instance.)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display: inline;` to your class :

```
.text p {
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/5prgjppL/1/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  But the reason for having overflow:auto is so that the <p> elements do not break across a float edge.  It works with just one picture (see https://jsfiddle.net/5prgjppL/5/ and https://jsfiddle.net/5prgjppL/4/) But not with both.  Having display:inline merges the paragraphs into one which isn't what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

We found that it was trying to place the p's to the left of the first image and the right of the second image.  Since both images are 50% there was no room for them, they would then resize to 0xheaps and still not display correctly.  The answer was to give p **min-width: 10px**.  This would force the browser to send it all  to the right of the second image, (https://jsfiddle.net/5prgjppL/8/):

```
.text p {
  overflow: auto;
  min-width: 10px;
}
```